# Get ordered product details (ID, quantity) in functions.php file of theme - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress & WooCommerce to process my orders as a global payments solution.

I am redirecting my customers after the payment to a custom thank you page... I redirect them by adding this code in the "functions.php" file of my current active theme:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/success.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I am trying to add the "ORDERED" product ID to the URL.

so my code is now like that:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    global $product;
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        $id = $product->get_id();
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/success.php?pid='.$id );
        exit;
    }
}
```

It redirect great after the order successful but the value of `$id` is empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code;

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );

function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    global $product;
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        $order_id = isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ? intval( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) : 0;
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        }

        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com/success.php?pid='.$product_id );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you very much. I used `$product_quantity = $item['qty'];` to get the ordered quantity too :)